# Phonertc demo works only windows x windows in browser but not working in devices

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ionic-framework, webrtc, phonertc

I have two problems.

1 - This only works with windows x windows chrome. If I test with ubuntu or mac with chrome, doesn´t work, I can login, but I call another user and stay the screen and call in process...

2 - In device, line var socket = io.connect('http://myserver.com:3000/'); I have this error :

"http://myserver.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1446506264545-0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: What version of socket.io is this?

Comment: The version is 1.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to discourage you from PhoneRTC but my team spent a lot of time working with it and after running into lots of issues we ended up using this cordova plugin instead: https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc . It seems to be a more active project, exposes the standard WebRTC API and so far its worked really well for us. If you want to play with a sample of it in action you can go here: https://github.com/WASdev/sample.rtcomm.mobile

Comment: Thank´s bpulito, I´ll try it. Do you know if it has a great support ?
About the node server, error 404, I don´t know if my server is correct, have you ever any idea ?